# How to hide QMessageBox when the Standard Buttons are clicked?

Tags: c++, qt, qmessagebox

What I want to achieve here is, when I click the close button(X) or the standard buttons(OK|Yes|No|...) on the `QMessageBox`, instead of closing the `QMessageBox`, I just want to hide it.

I override the `closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)` function, so when I click the close button(X), the `QMessageBox` will just hide. I did some research online to try to hide the `QMessageBox` when click the `OK` button, some people are saying I should override the `QDialog::reject()` function, but I did not make it work. 
So here is a minimal example of what I am trying to do:

```
MessageBox::MessageBox(QWidget *parent) : QMessageBox(parent)
{
    this->setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
    int ret = this->exec();

    switch (ret) {
    case QMessageBox::Ok:
        //confusing part
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void MessageBox::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    event->ignore();
    this->hide();
}

void MessageBox::reject()
{
    //I am confused about how to do this part to hide the message box when the OK button is clicked.
}
```

Hope someone can provide me a way to do this? Thanks.

**Edit: Why I want to do this?**
I have an app mostly running in the background, so most of the time, the windows are hid. When I click the check updates action from the tray icon menu, a `QMesssageBox` will pop up to show if there is a update available. And then if I click the buttons on the `QMessageBox`, the app will just quit. But also I've noticed, if I have an active window, when I click the buttons on the `QMessageBox`, the app will not quit. So I just want to stop my app from quitting after clicking buttons on the `QMessageBox` when there are no other active windows. Hope I explain myself clearly.

Comment: The OK button would call `accept()`, not `reject()`. You could also just create non-standard buttons and call `hide()` in their respective slots. But the whole question makes me wonder: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Do not overwrite reject.

Comment: @KarstenKoop I edited my question on why I want to hide the message box